# Calling a stored procedure with Ref cursor as output parameter using Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library

I am new to both Oracle and Entlib.

I have written some code to call a stored procedure which works fine, however there's an issue when I am calling stored procedure with Ref cursor as output parameter.

Could anybody help me with some sample code to access stored procedure inside Oracle database using EntLib which returns a Ref cursor as output parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Also: ***what*** is the issue/problem you're having? Please explain, post the exact and complete error message if you have one - something..... don't just tease us about issues - **tell us** what they are!

Comment: I am sorry. Next time i will make sure i include code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the tests in the source code.

First define a [cursor](https://daab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BVT/Data.BVT/DatabaseSetupScripts/OracleDBScripts/3.SP/1.cursor.sql):

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE
IS
TYPE CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE IS REF CURSOR;
END PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE;
```

Then create a [stored procedure](https://daab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BVT/Data.BVT/DatabaseSetupScripts/OracleDBScripts/3.SP/GETCUSTOMERSVIEW.prc):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GETCUSTOMERSVIEW" ( cur_OUT OUT PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE.CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE)
    AS

BEGIN
   OPEN cur_OUT FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId in ('BLAUS','BLONP','BOLID')
    ORDER BY CustomerID;
END;
/
```

Note use of cur_out as the ref cursor name -- this is mandatory.

Then the [c# code](https://daab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BVT/Data.BVT/OracleDatabaseFixtures/ExecuteReaderFixture.cs):

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@"Testfiles\Customers.xml")]
    [DeploymentItem(@"Testfiles\Products.xml")]
    public void RecordsAreReturnedWhenUsingStoredProc()
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("OracleTest");
        string spName = "GetCustomersView";
        using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName))
        {
            int columns = dsCustomers.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(dsCustomers.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim(), reader[j].ToString().Trim());
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The test uses [this configuration file](https://daab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BVT/Data.BVT/ConfigFiles/OracleDatabaseFixture.config).

If you are using ODP.NET then you would want to switch from using the deprecated System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle.DataAccess.Client.  You would need to use the EntlibContrib [Oracle ODP.NET Data Provider](https://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OracleDataProvider41&referringTitle=Home).  Also, you could look at the [EntLibContrib Quickstart](https://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EntLibContrib6Src/Quick%20Starts/Data.OdpNet/CS/) for sample ODP.NET configuration.